# ¿Promedio dentro de un ciclo? en JAVA

Tags: java

Como pueden ver mi código lo que hace es generar una corrida de 3 numeros aleatorios, para eso utilizo un ciclo que va contando K , estoy guardando esos números en un arreglo para posteriormente sumarlos y obtener el promedio, pero sucede que necesito hacerlo para cada K , es decir cuando k = 1 imprime 1 resultado aleatorio lo suma y genera el promedio, y asi para 2, 3 , 4 hasta llegar a k= 30.

Cómo podría hacer esto? Eh intentado ya algunas cosas y ninguna me resulta.

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        double x;   //aleatoria
        double promedio=0;
        double total =0;



        for(int k=1; k<31; k++){

            x = 0+Math.random()*1;

            double arr[] = {x};

            System.out.println(x);

            for(int contador=0;contador<arr.length;contador++){
                total+=arr[contador];
            }
            promedio = total/30; 

        }

        System.out.println("El total es: "+total);
        System.out.println("El promedio es: "+ promedio);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Dentro del `for`, usa la variable llamada `i`, es más genérico que
   `K`.
2. No tienes que guardar el valor generado en un array, es innecesario.
3. No tienes que tener un `for` dentro del `for` principal, también es
   innecesario.
4. El promedio puedes calcularlo al final, fuera del `for` principal.
5. En el `for` principal tienes `k < 31`, puedes simplemente decir `k <= 30`.
6. Puedes ir sumando los valores dentro del mismo `for` principal,
   ejemplo: `total += valorAleatorio;`
7. Como sugerencia, puedes declarar una variable constante al inicio
   del programa igualada a 30. Con esto, no tendrás que cambiar este
   valor en cada parte del código cuando desees más/menos números
   generados. Ejemplo: `final int CANTIDAD_NUMEROS = 30;`. Una constante es una variable del sistema que mantiene un valor inmutable a lo largo de toda la vida del programa.

**Código con el ejercicio resuelto y mejorado:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double valorAleatorio; // aleatoria
        double promedio = 0;
        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {

            valorAleatorio = 0 + Math.random() * 1;

            System.out.println("[" + i + "] " + valorAleatorio);

            // Sumar valores (es lo mismo que decir: total = total + valorAleatorio)
            total += valorAleatorio;

        }

        // Promedio
        promedio = total / 30;

        System.out.println("El total es: " + total);
        System.out.println("El promedio es: " + promedio);

    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.

Comment: Hola , muchas gracias por tu respuesta la verdad es que me ayudó a darme cuenta de lo mucho que me falta por aprender, y si se simplificó más el codigo! soy nuevo aquí en StackOverflow, gracias de verdad por tu respuesta.

Comment: @AlexPalacios es un placer ayudarte amigo. Todo se aprende poco a poco, verás que en cuestión de tiempo tendrás muchas habilidades más. Me alegra haberte ayudado. Si puedes, selecciona mi Respuesta como la Elegida y vota por ella. Saludos.